# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException

Tags: mysql, vb.net, rdlc

Good day! Can someone help me with this? I can't figure out why this error appears. What should I do?

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') and cdr_datetime BETWEEN '2015-01-01 12:00:00' AND '2015-12-29
>   23:59:59' group' at line 18"

This is my code:

```
Case "employeewithoutdestination"
    Dim newparams(3) As ReportParameter
        newparams(0) = New ReportParameter("CallClassCode", callClassCode)
        newparams(1) = New ReportParameter("DateTimeFrom", startDateTime)
        newparams(2) = New ReportParameter("DateTimeTo", endDateTime)
        newparams(3) = New ReportParameter("Vat", vat)
       rvScreen.LocalReport.SetParameters(newparams)
       rvScreen.LocalReport.Refresh()

    Dim rdsEmployeeWithoutDestination As New ReportDataSource
    Dim daEmployeeWithoutDestination As New EmployeeWithoutDestinationTableAdapter
    Dim dtEmployeeWithoutDestination As New EmployeeWithoutDestinationDataTable

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(reportFilter) Then
      daEmployeeWithoutDestination.SetWhereClause(String.Format("cdr_site_id = '{0}' and a.employee_id in ({1}) and cdr_datetime BETWEEN '{2}' AND '{3}' group by cdr_date,cdr_time,cdr_call_type_code ORDER BY employee_name", siteId, employeeId, startDateTime, endDateTime))
    Else
      daEmployeeWithoutDestination.SetWhereClause(String.Format("cdr_site_id = '{0}' and a.employee_id in ({1}) and cdr_datetime BETWEEN '{2}' AND '{3}' group by cdr_date,cdr_time,cdr_call_type_code ORDER BY employee_name", siteId, employeeId, startDateTime, endDateTime))
    End If

      daEmployeeWithoutDestination.Fill(dtEmployeeWithoutDestination)

      rdsEmployeeWithoutDestination.Name = "LCSRDBDataSet_EmployeeWithoutDestination"
      rdsEmployeeWithoutDestination.Value = dtEmployeeWithoutDestination
      rvScreen.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdsEmployeeWithoutDestination)
```

[image: error]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect `employeeId` is empty, so you have `a.employee_id in ()`.

Comment: Why do you have the same code in both branches of the `If`?

Comment: I only copied and pasted the code which runs. I don't know why this error appears when I changed the table adapter to have the report separated.

Comment: The query you show at the bottom is not the query that's getting the error. It doesn't have `and cdr_datetime BETWEEN`

Comment: That appears in the call to `SetWhereClause`

Comment: Okay. I should remove it.

Comment: What is the value of `employeeId`?

Comment: Checked it from my database. It's unique. One is '98974ba3-81e4-11e5-8f2a-f3dc77bf556e'

Comment: Not the value in the database. I'm guessing that the problem is that the variable is empty in the program, so an empty string is being substituted into the SQL.

Comment: Also, if it's a string like that, you need quotes around it: `a.employee_id in ('{1}')`

Comment: Why do you have `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` in the argument to `SetWhereClause`? Those aren't part of the `WHERE` clause, they're separate clauses of their own.

Comment: How can I separate it? And when I changed it to a.employee_id in ('{1}'), it runs without syntax error but it does not show the data.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by separate it. You need to figure out why the `employeeId` variable doesn't contain the employee ID that you're trying to search for.

Comment: @Barmar, when I changed it to this code:                    daEmployeeWithoutDestination.SetWhereClause(String.Format("cdr_site_id = '{0}' and a.employee_code in ({1}) group by cdr_date,cdr_time,cdr_call_type_code", siteId, "'LCS0151','LCS0212','LCS1525'")) , it runs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99166/discussion-between-lyra-opena-and-barmar).